# Move mysql data from one table to another with escaped values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am moving data from 1 table to another and it works apart from the free text fields which may contain some single and double quotes.

I've only included the troublesome values and these are passed from a form on the previous page, then retrieved with:

```
$Con_Details = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Con_Details']);
$Res_Response = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Res_Response']);
```

The data goes into the first table like this.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO t_table
 (Con_Details,Res_Response) VALUES ('$Con_Details','$Res_Response')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Later I show the rows in a table and when a row is selected, all the values are retrieved by the next page again with:

```
$Con_Details = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Con_Details']);
$Res_Response = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Res_Response']);
```

They are shown in a table like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr>
<td width="200" align="right" valign="top">Concern Details:<br> (Max 500)</td>
<td colspan="3" bgcolor="#ffffff"><?php echo "$Con_Details"; ?></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr><td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<td width="200" align="right" valign="top">Response Details:<br> (Max 500)</td>
<td colspan="3" bgcolor="#ffffff"><?php echo "$Res_Response"; ?></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

One of the values displays like this "Don't show full text" and the other displays like this "Don\'t show full text"

I want to move the rows to a new table but it truncates the field and only shows "Don\" OR "Don\"

How do I do this move as both tables are not identical, they both have an auto increment id, but table 2 also has a column called "id_orig" which stores the id it had in table 1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alas, in PHP you need to use different escaping mechanisms for different targets.

`mysqli_real_escape_string()` is useful only for building MySQL statements in the `mysqli_*` API.

`urldecode()` for building urls.

`htmlentities()` for escaping `&`, `<`, and other things when constructing an HTML page.

Your first use of `mysqli_real_escape_string()` was correct; the second should have used `htmlentities()` instead.

Some other notes...

When reading data from MySQL (eg, with `SELECT`), you do not need to un-escape the strings returned.

PHP's ["magic quotes"](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php), depending on the settings you have, may be messing with `$_GET` and `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` values before you see them.  If so, *then* you need to do some kind of un-escape.  (The details depend on which setting you have.)  The likely characters to be mangled include `"&<>'\`.  Suggest putting them in a `form`, then do `echo strlen()` to see if it is 6 characters or has some escaping added.